# Unable to install Maven on Windows: "JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory"

Tags: java, maven-2

I followed [the Maven tutorial](http://maven.apache.org/download.html#Installation) to the letter but I still can't get Maven installed on Windows.

When I run the following in command prompt:

```
E:\Documents and Settings\zach>mvn --version
```

I get:

```
'mvn' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

I navigated to the maven install folder and ran `mvn --version` and got:

```
E:\java resources\apache-maven-2.2.0\bin>mvn --version
ERROR: JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory.
JAVA_HOME = "E:\Sun\SDK\jdk\bin"
Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the
location of your Java installation
```

but when I run `java -version` I get:

```
java version "1.6.0_14"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_14-b08)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 14.0-b16, mixed mode)
```

So I do have Java installed. Anyone know what the problem is?

Answer (score 175, accepted):

The problems are to do with your paths.

1. Make sure that the directory "E:\java resources\apache-maven-2.2.0\bin" is on your command search path.
2. Make sure that the JAVA_HOME variable refers to the *home directory* for your Java installation.  If you are executing Java from "E:\Sun\SDK\jdk\bin", then the JAVA_HOME variable needs to point to "E:\Sun\SDK\jdk".

   NB: JAVA_HOME should NOT end with "\bin"<sup>1</sup>.
3. Make sure that you haven't put a semicolon in the JAVA_HOME variable<sup>2</sup>.

   NB: JAVA_HOME should be a single directory name, not "PATH-like" list of directory names separated by semicolons.

Also note that you could run into problems if you have ignored this advice in the [Maven on Windows](http://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/windows-prerequisites.html) instructions about spaces in key pathnames.

> "Maven, like many cross-platform tools, can encounter problems *when there are space characters in important pathnames*."
>
> "You need to install the Java SDK (e.g. from Oracle's download site), and you should install it *to a pathname without spaces*, such as c:\j2se1.6."'
>
> "You need to unpack the Maven distribution. Don't unpack it in the middle of your source code; pick some location (*with no spaces in the path!*) and unpack it there."

The simple remedy for this would be to reinstall Java or Maven in a different location so that there *isn't* a space in the path

---

<sup>1 - .... unless you have made an *insane* choice for the name for your installation location.</sup>

<sup>2 - Apparently a common "voodoo" solution to Windows path problems is to whack a semicolon on the end.  It is not recommended in general, absolutely does not work here.</sup>

Answer (score 30):

> ERROR: JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory. JAVA_HOME = "E:\Sun\SDK\jdk\bin" Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the location of your Java installation

`JAVA_HOME` should be set to `E:\Sun\SDK\jdk`. 
`PATH` should be set to include `%JAVA_HOME%\bin`.

Answer (score 13):

I ran into this issue with a Grails install.

The problem was my **JAVA_HOME** was `c:\sun\jdk\` and my **PATH** has `%JAVA_HOME%bin`

I changed it to: `JAVA_HOME= "c:\sun\jdk" and PATH="%JAVA_HOME%\bin"`

It worked after that.

Answer (score 10):

I was facing the same issue and just updated the JAVA_HOME worked for me.

previously it was like this:    C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_45\bin
 Just removed the \bin and it worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

Due to security restrictions at my current place of work I was unable to set enviroment variables on my Windows based PC.

My workaround was to copy the mvn.bat file from %M2% into C:\WINNT and add the following to the top of the batch file:

```
@REM Needed as unable to set env variables on my desktop PC.

set MAVEN_OPTS=-Xms256m -Xmx1024m
set M2_HOME=C:\apache-maven-3.0.4
set M2=%M2_HOME%\bin
set JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.5.0_15
set PATH=%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%M2%;%PATH%
```

Not the nicest solution but it works. If anybody has any other way or work-around where the standard env vars are not able to be set into the system I'd welcome their response.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue and none of the above answers fixed it for me because my env variables were all set. I had just reinstalled my Java.

What worked was to

1. go to the `C:\path\to\apache-maven-3.0.4\bin` and open the `mvn.bat` file.
2. Find the line that looks like this `@SET JAVA_HOME=C:\progra~1\java\jdk1.7.0_03`
3. Correct it to the right path

I don't know if this is Windows specific, but it might help someone!

Answer (score 2):

After lot of failed tried attempts ,I found the solution

It was the ";" at end of JAVA_HOME which I always put at end of each new variable I set.
So get rid of the ;.

JAVA_HOME set it in User Variable also (without the ";" ofcourse)

Comment: *"... which I always put at end of each new variable I set"* - Why would you do that?

Answer (score 1):

you should set JAVA_HOME or MAVEN_HOME without bin directory
for example:
 - JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_45
 - MAVEN_HOME=C:\Program Files (x86)\apache-maven-3.1.1
now 
path=.....;%MAVEN_HOME%\bin;%JAVA_HOME%\bin
it's work correctly

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes in Windows whitespaces in paths are not recognized correctly

If you have a path problem and path seems like

`c:\Program Files\....`

try changing it in an old DOS format like

`"C:\Progra~1\...`

You can use `dir /x` to check correct syntax (third column)

`C:\>dir /x
    ...
    11.01.2008  15:47    <DIR>          DOCUME~1     Documents and Settings
    01.12.2006  09:10    <DIR>          MYPROJ~1     My Projects
    21.01.2011  14:08    <DIR>          PROGRA~1     Program Files
    ...`

In my pc JAVA_HOME is (and it works)

`"C:\Progra~1\Java\jdk1.8.0_121"`

Tested in Windows 10

Answer (score 0):

JAVA_HOME should be like this C:\PROGRA~1\Java\jdk

Hope this will work!

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be old post but still I wanted to share how this issue got fixed for me.

For users, who do not have admin access and when they open a command prompt, it runs under the user privilege. It means, you may have path like C:\Users\

so when trying C:\Users\XYZ>mvn --version , it actually search the JAVA_HOME path from user variables not system variables in Environment Variables.

So, In order to fix this, we need to create a environment variable for JAVA_HOME in user variables.

Hope, this helps someone.

Comment: Ermmm ... The user's environment variables override the system environment variables on Windows.  If you have a system and user environment variable with the same name, then the user variable "wins", and that what the application sees.

Answer (score 0):

Running eclipse and also running Maven will require you to store two path variables, one in your jdk1.7_x_x_x location and also in your jdk1.7_x_x_\bin.  If you are using Windows, when you are in your environment variables, do the following:

1) create a USER variable called JAVA_HOME.  Point this to the location of your JAVA file.  For example: "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51" (remove the quotes)

2) under the PATH, append %JAVA_HOME% to the PATH.  This will add the file location from step 1 to your PATH.  This is good for MAVEN

3) if you are using eclipse you need to have the path point to "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\bin".  Now append %JAVA_HOME%\bin to the end of your path.

4) your path should look something like this:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\;C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\npm;%M2%;%JAVA_HOME%;%JAVA_HOME%\bin

Notes: the items that are enclosed in %'s like %M2% are assigned variables. It looks redundant but necessary.  You can confirm that everything works by typing in:

java -version 
javac -version 
mvn -version

Each of those three statements typed in comman prompt should not return errors.

Comment: Step 2) is incorrect and unnecessary.  Neither the Java toolchain or Maven require %JAVA_HOME% to be in the "PATH" variable.  (It won't do any *real* harm, but does no good either.)  Reference - http://www.tutorialspoint.com/maven/maven_environment_setup.htm

Answer (score 0):

**using windows 10**

I was facing issue .. then I **removed JAVA_HOME** variable completly and just **added %JAVA_HOME%\bin**  in PATH then it worked!!! for mee

Comment: Thanks.It works for after adding "/bin" at the end of Java_home variable

Answer (score -1):

The JDK has switched locations of java.exe between 1.6 and 1.7!!!

In my case I found that the JAVA_HOME for the JDK had to add the \jre on the end. The mvn bat file is looking for java.exe and it looks for it in JAVA_HOME\bin. Its not there for JDK 1.7; it is in JAVA_HOME\jre\bin. In JDK 1.6 such it IS in JAVA_HOME\bin.

Hope this helps somebody.

Comment: I believe this is incorrect.  According to the Official Oracle Documentation for Java 7 (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/jdkfiles.html), in a JDK installation the "java" command appears both in "JAVA_HOME\bin" and "JAVA_HOME\jre\bin".  If this is not so in your installation, then someone / something has messed around with it!

Comment: Interesting. It is not in my /bin directory, just my /jre/bin. Maybe I need to re-install the latest JDK

Answer (score -1):

My situation was a bit different.

- `JAVA_HOME` was set properly to point to 1.7
- Other Maven projects were working/building fine with 1.7 features.
- `PATH` was set properly.
- Everything was up-to-date.

Still my simple new Maven project was not working. What I noticed was the difference in the logs when I ran `mvn clean install`. For my older Maven projects, it showed

```
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) @ oldProject---
```

But for my new project it showed:

```
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.0.2:compile (default-compile) @ newProject ---
```

So, I looked at the `POM.xml` and noticed this thing in the old project's POM:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Basically, this plugin tells which compiler version to use for compilation. Just added it to the new project's `POM.xml` and things worked.

Hope it is useful to someone.

Comment: This is not a valid answer to this question.  The symptoms are different.  The solution is different.

Answer (score -1):

I am using Windows 7, the problem I had was simple:

I had this for my JAVA_HOME environment variable value:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51;"
```

when it wants:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51"
```

the semi-colon strikes again!

:)

This is how I solved this problem, so this should be one possible solution.