# Java is Set to an Invalid Directory

Tags: java, jvm

I am trying to set up maven, however when I tried `maven --version`

note I already viewed this question
[Unable to install Maven on Windows: "JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184056/unable-to-install-maven-java-home-is-set-to-an-invalid-directory)

I tried the solutions here but it still did not work.
however still di not work

here is the error

```
ERROR: JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory.
JAVA_HOME = "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_24\bin\java.exe"
Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match th
location of your Java installation
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Set the *environment variable* named `JAVA_HOME` to where the JDK is installed, i.e.

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_24
```

Comment: and the path might present a problem. Used to be paths with whitespace of ascii characters would confuse the Java compilers if they were installed on them (despite being the default installation directory on Windows). Not sure if that's fixed by now, for safety I've not installed a JDK except in the root or a /tools directory for ages).

Comment: I tried that few minutes ago, and it didn't work! I cannot understand why! What I did was 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_24;'

Answer (score 0):

I faced the similar situation.

The solution is to remove the semicolon(`;`) at the end of `JAVA_HOME`.

```
JAVA_HOME = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_11
```

instead of

```
JAVA_HOME = "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_11;"
```

Answer (score -1):

If you didn't install java and did copy paste it then set the **JAVA_HOME**

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_24\bin
```

and add it to the **path** variable as well