# I am trying to conform maven installation from command prompt but getting an error

Tags: java, maven

When I run command `mvn --version` I get the error shown into image. How can I resolve it?

[image: **** **]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unable to install Maven on Windows: "JAVA\_HOME is set to an invalid directory"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184056/unable-to-install-maven-on-windows-java-home-is-set-to-an-invalid-directory)

Answer (score 0):

Remove `\bin` from your JAVA_HOME path and replace it with `\jre` in case you need JRE only.

**EDIT**: in case you need some development tools from JDK you should just remove `\bin` form your path

Answer (score 0):

Remove \bin from your JAVA_HOME path and replace it with \jdk

for me it is **`JAVA_HOME: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45`**

Answer (score 0):

Maven is asking Java Installation Directory In your case it should be as following

- C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_40

Answer (score 0):

Solved! i just removed ; from my JAVA_HOME environment variable.